# How to use the 'count' parameter in tweepy's streaming API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I can use the streaming API just fine when I don't include the `count` parameter in `filter()` call, but when I try to specify how many tweets from my history I want to receive, my stream object returns `None`.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener, Stream

class Listener (StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print '-' * 20
        print status.text
        return

def get_tweets(request):
    # if request.is_ajax():
    # All keys and secrets are declared here, but were removed for security reasons.

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    listener = Listener()
    stream = Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter(follow=("14739093",), count=-5)
```

I also tried the following, to see what it was returning.

```
>>> something = stream.filter(follow=("14739093",), count=-5)
>>> print something
None
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I have tried a positive number, and it does the same thing. Without, the count parameter, the filter just runs continuously, and prints out any tweets. But, when I give it the count parameter, it just goes to a new line (>>>) in python.

Comment: `on_error` specifically will stop things immediately unless you override it.

Comment: Alright, I overrode the on_error() method and it's giving me 416 Range Unacceptable. Possible reasons are: Count parameter is not allowed in role. Count parameter value is too large. Since it's obviously not too large, it must not be allowed in that role. I'm still not sure on why it's giving me that error, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Stream.filter` always returns `None`, its job is just to pass the data on to the `StreamListener`.

Your problem is that Twitter only allows the `count` parameter for certain "roles".

> Firehose, Links, Birddog and Shadow clients interested in capturing all statuses should maintain a current estimate of the number of statuses received per second and note the time that the last status was received. Upon a reconnect, the client can then estimate the appropriate backlog to request. **Note that the count parameter is not allowed elsewhere, including track, sample and on the default access role.**

This is the reason you're getting a `413` error when you try to use the `count` parameter -- you're on the "default access" role.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarifying that for me. I don't enough reputation to upvote this answer, but I would if I could!

Comment: A true gem -- NOT easy to find things on twitter docs sometimes. Thanks!